RN Android restarts activity when locale changes
I want to configure changing the locale based on the setting.
Once the user has selected the language, AppCompatDelegate API is called, to inform Android about the language change. Per-app language preferences
But the app is restarted. How to avoid restarting the app when the locale is changed?
In the manifest already added the locale to android:configChanges
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">

Here is my module:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import androidx.core.os.LocaleListCompat
import android.os.Build
import com.facebook.react.bridge.*

class LocaleModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

  override fun getName(): String {
    return "LocaleModule"
  }

  @ReactMethod
  fun setApplicationLocales(localesArray: ReadableArray, promise: Promise) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
      try {
        val locales = Array(localesArray.size()) { "" }
        for (i in 0 until localesArray.size()) {
          locales[i] = localesArray.getString(i) ?: ""
        }
        val localeList = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(locales.joinToString(","))
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(localeList)
        promise.resolve(null)
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        promise.reject("ERROR", e.message ?: "Unknown error")
      }
    } else {
      promise.reject("UNSUPPORTED", "API level is below 33")
    }
  }

  @ReactMethod
  fun getApplicationLocales(promise: Promise) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
      try {
        val localeList = AppCompatDelegate.getApplicationLocales()
        val localesArray = WritableNativeArray()
        for (i in 0 until localeList.size()) {
          localesArray.pushString(localeList[i]?.toLanguageTag())
        }
        promise.resolve(localesArray)
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        promise.reject("ERROR", e.message ?: "Unknown error")
      }
    } else {
      promise.reject("UNSUPPORTED", "API level is below 33")
    }
  }
}

Package:
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext

class LocalePackage: ReactPackage {
  override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> {
    return emptyList()
  }

  override fun createNativeModules(
    reactContext: ReactApplicationContext
  ): List<NativeModule> {
    return listOf(LocaleModule(reactContext))
  }
}


I think you need to be a bit more precise in your language, to make sure we understand the problem.  The app would never be restarted on a config change.  That would mean the process is killed.  The activity would be restarted by default, although you seem to have turned that off.  You can verify that by putting a log in onCreate.  The ReactNative code could be restarted, but for that we'd need to see how you actually launch and restart the react native library
